# How to write simple unit tests to test the parsing of a JSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, unit-testing

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    } else {
        NSError *e = nil;
        NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

        if (!jsonDict) {
            NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
        } else {


        }
    }
}];
```

Hi There,

I am trying to write a simple unit test to check if the parsing of the json was successful?

I have no experience with unit testing.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test parser method. Then you can create a dummy jsonDict in Test Class. Call you parser method with that jsonDict.

```
-(void) testParserMethod {
        // jsonDict = {} // fill according to your method need
        // let say our parser method require a dictionary containing name and age. and set our object. then we can create a dict like this.
       NSDictionary jsonDict= @{ @"name" : @"name", 
                @"age" : @"age",
              };
        YourObject object = [YourParserClass parseMethed:jsonDict]

        XCTAssertEqual(object.name, jsonDict[@"name"])
        XCTAssertEqual(object.age, jsonDict[@"age"])
}
```

If object is set correctly with the dummy jsonDict that we provide. then the test case will pass.

Comment: Hey, What do you mean by dummy jsonDict? Should that dict contain anything or be a blank dict?

Comment: dummy jsonDict will contain some data that you are expecting to come from server. in unit testing we don't include server. So we just hardcode our dictionary to test our method.

Comment: what about the setUp and tearDown methods? not needed?

Comment: how to pass jsonDict to your method? For example I got response with needed NSDictionary and I want to compare it with etalon dictionary?